# Send command to java application from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, monodevelop

I have a java application (craftBukkit) running in terminal on a mac. I am writing a webpage (running with asp net) to add a user to a list. after that completes i need to send the command "reload" to the java application as if I typed it into the terminal that it is running in.

The java app is not to quit or restart... just receive a command.

Is this possible? Both are running on the same computer.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java application lives in a "sandbox", the **easiest** way in my opinion is to listen to UDP socket in the Java side and send a message to reload from the C# application.

**EDIT::**

Another approach, that might fit you, although I'm not familiar with C#, invoke the java program as a process from your program, and grab IO streams, when needed, print "reload" to the java app input stream.

Comment: if i understand correctly, there is a problem. I do not own the code for the java application, so I cannot tell it to listen for the command.

Comment: You do understand correctly. But in this case, your question is not clear. do you want to reload the java application once the task you mention was completed?

Comment: Sorry... The java app should always be running, but sent a command, as if i were typing it into the terminal by hand.

Comment: In this case I can't help. I think you should remove Java tag.

Comment: @Adam8797 - please edit your question and clarify it, I bet I'm not the only one to misunderstand you...

Comment: I was doing some more research and someone else had suggested something similar. I am trying it now. Thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replies. It seems to be working ok now. Again, thank you.